# Manually override DataTable's Language.infoFiltered

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to override the total, unfiltered count within DataTables.  Currently our application receives information via AJAX which must be formatted and processed and is then manually added to a `<table>`.  It seems for dynamic infromation this is normally received in the JSON AJAX response but once again, we must do processing beforehand.

Currently I have a partial fix that looks something like this:

```
if(typeof $.overrideFilteredCount == 'undefined') {
    $.overrideFilteredCount = '_MAX_';
}

$.dataTable = $sortTable.DataTable({
    'language': {
        "infoFiltered": "(" + $.overrideFilteredCount + " total entries)"
    },
});
```

However this has the effect of always displaying the "filtered" text to the user, since we always use a filter, e.x.:

> Showing 1 to 10 of 54 entries (54 total entries)

Is there a way to dynamically set the total count post-initialization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [infoCallback](http://datatables.net/reference/option/infoCallback) option to define a callback function to dynamically update the informational section.

For example:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
  "infoCallback": function( settings, start, end, max, total, pre ) {
     return "Showing " + start + " to " + end + " of " + total + " entries"
            + ((total !== max) ? " (filtered from " + max + " total entries)" : "");
  }
});
```

Comment: It took me a minute to realize how to use this, but I get it now.  I seen that in the documentation but the application of it went straight over my head.  Thanks a ton!